# How to echo a PHP variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to echo a PHP variable into JavaScript. But I have no experience about JavaScript, I did some research but nothing worked for me.

The code

```
 function hide() {
   document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="none";
   <?php echo $myVar; ?>
 }
```

And the $myVar looks like:

```
$myVar = "Hi there";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this in js :

```
var php_val = '<?php echo $myVar; ?>';
 alert(php_val);
```

Comment: Tried this to, but the button not works then.

Comment: if you are changing the js value after page load then it didn't work.Before page load it have to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $var="blah"; ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 alert('<?php echo $var ?>');
 </script>
```

Comment: Tried this to, but nothing happens as well when it loads finish.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$myVar = 'var myVar="Hi here"'
```

or

```
function hide() {
   document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="none";
   var myVar='<?php echo $myVar; ?>'
 }
```

Comment: Tried this, but nothing actually happens after it loading finish. :(

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways to write PHP variable in javascript:

**First Way:**

JavaScript written in the php page or inline:

EX:

```
<?php 
   $myVar = 'hello';
?>
....
<script>
function hide() {
   document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display="none";
   <?php echo $myVar; ?>
}
</script>
```

**Second way:**

Put your variables on the top of your page, like baseUrl for example, and use it in separated JavaScript file but you have to write the variables before load JavaScript files.

```
EX:
<head>
<script>
    var baseUrl = <?php echo $thisPageUrl; ?>
</script>
</head>
....

<script src="myscriptfile.js"></script>
```